# Removing embedded tomcat server from war file when deploying to JBOSS [Spring-Boot]

Tags: spring-boot, jboss

I am using intellij and instead of manually removing the tomcat jar's from the war file what is a better way to remove them during compilation.

I need this done because I am getting the following error:

```
failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" =>    
{"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host.\"/request-ws-
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service 
jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host.\"/request-ws-
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\": java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer cannot be cast to 
io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer
```

However when I remove the tomcat jar's everything is fine.

I am using Gradle and I want to REMOVE tomcat when I run it using JBOSS. However when I run it using spring-boot I want/need it there.

Answer (score 1):

If you use maven then you need to set the tomcat dependency scope as `provided` in your `pom.xml` as described in http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <!-- ... -->
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <!-- ... -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ... -->
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Gradle users should use `providedRuntime` as described in http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html.

```
...
apply plugin: 'war'

war {
    baseName = 'myapp'
    version =  '0.5.0'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am using Gradle and I want to REMOVE it and I do have the above dependencies. However when I run it on BOSS I don't want it in the war file but when I run it using spring-boot I do.