# Maven dependency exclusion of Tomcat doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, tomcat

I created a maven-based spring-boot-project to explore how to make it run on a Websphere Application Server.
This is way I need to exclude the Embedded Tomcat of spring-boot-starter-web.

I've tried the following things:

Added a new dependency for spring-boot-starter-tomcat with the scope: provided (see [Removing embedded tomcat server from war file when deploying to JBOSS [Spring-Boot]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40770575/removing-embedded-tomcat-server-from-war-file-when-deploying-to-jboss-spring-bo)) followed by a mvn clean update.

Used the exclusions-tag in the spring-boot-starter-web dependency to exclude spring-boot-starter-tomcat (see https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) followed by a mvn clean update.

Neither of those works.

Here is my 'native' POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
      <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      ...
    </dependencies>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is my dependency with explicit Tomcat (scope: provided):

```
<project ...>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is my dependency with the exclusion:

```
<project ...>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring‑boot‑starter‑tomcat</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is the output of mvn dependency:tree:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbbJx.jpg
(Sorry I don't know how to upload pictures here.)

I'd expect the Tomcat to be removed from my maven dependencies.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be more specific in what doesn't work. For starters I don't see anywhere you are building a WAR hence you probably get a JAR and that simply cannot be deployed to websphere. You also don't define how you are building your artifact.

Comment: Well actually I do but i though its not needed to provide will edit it in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Running your exclusions example that you posted ran fine when i build it .

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Also I did mvn clean install after adding this exclusion and my dependency tree also doesn't include tomcat jar anymore :

[image: Screenshot of dependency tree]

Did you mvn clean install after adding the exclusions ?